# I only get one whatsapp answer via dialogflow instead of multiple replies

Tags: python, twilio, dialogflow-es, chatbot

How do I get multiple 'text answers' in whatsApp? When I add more than one 'text response' in intents they work normally in the dialogFlow console.

But when I repeat the same question on whatsapp I get only one answer box instead of 3, for example, that I had created.

I am using twilio to communicate with the whatsapp API. I also use Horoku cloud services to host the application.

Everything works normal. But I received only one message box instead of multiple in whatsapp.
I think the problem is my python code 'app.py'.

## app.py

```
@app.route("/") #just to test Heroku cloud services
def hello():
    return "Hello, World!"

@app.route("/sms", methods=['POST'])
def sms_reply():
    """Respond to incoming calls with a simple text message."""
    # Fetch the message
    msg = request.form.get('Body')
    phone_no = request.form.get('From')
    reply = fetch_reply(msg, phone_no)

    # Create reply
    resp = MessagingResponse()
    resp.message(reply)
    enter code here
    return str(resp)
```

---

## utils.py

```
import dialogflow_v2 as dialogflow
dialogflow_session_client = dialogflow.SessionsClient()
PROJECT_ID = "weather-husgcf"

def detect_intent_from_text(text, session_id, language_code='pt-BR'):
    session = dialogflow_session_client.session_path(PROJECT_ID, session_id)
    text_input = dialogflow.types.TextInput(text=text, language_code=language_code)
    query_input = dialogflow.types.QueryInput(text=text_input)
    response = dialogflow_session_client.detect_intent(session=session, query_input=query_input)
    return response.query_result

def fetch_reply(query, session_id):
    response = detect_intent_from_text(query, session_id)
    return response.fulfillment_text
```

https://i.imgur.com/a/b2QSYUB "ScreenShots"

Comment: if you are sending multiple responses you can send for loop through

Comment: Hi friend. How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Old-ish question but here's the answer (Dialogflow v2).

Assuming you have some sort of `sendMessage(mobile_num, text)` function, you iterate over the `fulfillment_messages` like this:

```
for message in response.query_result.fulfillment_messages:
    sendMessage(mobile_num, message.text.text[0])
```

From the webhook you get a json like this:

```
{
  "queryText": string,
  "languageCode": string,
  "speechRecognitionConfidence": number,
  "action": string,
  "parameters": {
    object
  },
  "allRequiredParamsPresent": boolean,
  "cancelsSlotFilling": boolean,
  "fulfillmentText": string,
  "fulfillmentMessages": [
        {
            "text": {
                "text": [
                    "Some text"
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "text": {
                "text": [
                    "Some more text"
                ]
            }
        },
  ],
  "webhookSource": string,
  "webhookPayload": {
    object
  },
  "outputContexts": [
    {
      object (Context)
    }
  ],
  "intent": {
    object (Intent)
  },
  "intentDetectionConfidence": number,
  "diagnosticInfo": {
    object
  },
  "sentimentAnalysisResult": {
    object (SentimentAnalysisResult)
  }
}
```

where `fulfillmentMessages` is an array you have to iterate over.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

In your `fetch_reply` method you call on the `query_result`'s `fulfillment_text` property. According the [`QueryResult` documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.agent.sessions/detectIntent#QueryResult) fulfillmentText is deprecated/legacy:

> The text to be pronounced to the user or shown on the screen. Note: This is a legacy field, fulfillmentMessages should be preferred.

The `fullfillmentMessages` property is defined as a list of [Message](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.agent.intents#Message) objects. So to return all 3 of your messages your code should probably loop through the messages adding them to the response, something like this:

```
def fetch_reply(query, session_id):
    response = detect_intent_from_text(query, session_id)
    return response.fulfillment_messages
```

Then your route should look something like this:

```
@app.route("/sms", methods=['POST'])
def sms_reply():
    """Respond to incoming calls with a simple text message."""
    # Fetch the message
    msg = request.form.get('Body')
    phone_no = request.form.get('From')
    replies = fetch_reply(msg, phone_no)

    # Create reply
    resp = MessagingResponse()
    for reply in replies:
        resp.message(reply.text)
    return str(resp)
```

I haven't tested this, just worked from the [DialogFlow documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.agent.sessions/detectIntent#QueryResult). Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thanks to reply. I got error on "resp.message(reply.text)" -> 'expecedt an indented block'.

Comment: I’m not at a computer right now, but that seems like a python problem. I’m not normally a Python developer, so I bet you’re better placed to sort out my syntax errors, or just take the idea here, that you need to work with the list of `fulfillment_messages`, and run with it. Let me know how you get on.

Comment: Error on sms_reply: "cannot serialize %r (type %s)" % (text, type(text).__name__)"

Comment: I couldn't tell from the Dialogflow documentation, but `reply.text` might be an array? Perhaps you could check on that?

Comment: Yes, i think is an array. I'm new to python. Thanks for feedback.

Comment: Were you manage to solve the "Cannot serialize" issue because I am stuck on the same thing and I am not able to parse "fulfillment_message"?

Comment: @AliZaidi I think we worked out that `fulfillment_messages` is an array, so you can't just use it in place of a string. You would need to choose an item from the array, or loop through and use each item, depending on your use case.